# how to seize resource permanently using Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

is it possible to seize resource permanently to agent until end of model  .. like we assigning token

I try to use seize and service block with resource pool but its not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is not how seizing is supposed to work. If you want to permanently reduce the size of a resource pool by 1 (effectively what you want to do), then simply call

`myResourcePool.setCapacity(myResourcePool.getCapacity()-1);`